# How to invoke restart on condition from Sly/REPL?

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, sbcl, slime

Once after I made some error condition, I get a prompt looks like:

`[1] CL-USER>`

It seems like, the number in square bracket indicates number of restart conditions of current REPL.

But, IDK how can I (re-)invoke the restart from REPL. (I'm using SBCL/Sly)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sly should be creating a separate buffer for the debugger (which should open in a split window). There must be something wrong with your emacs configuration if you're not seeing that (check if you have a buffer named `*sly-db for sbcl ...*` that's just not getting displayed for some reason).

Comment: Thank you so much.